# How do you iterate over Matrix field in a Craft 3 plugin?

Tags: matrix, craft3

```
$entry = Entry::find()->section('my_section')->relatedTo($entry)->all();
$entry['myMatrixField']; // What do I do with this??
```

I know there are tutorials about how to handle Matrix fields in plugins in Craft 2, but how do I do this in Craft 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a Matrix field with a handle of `matrix` and it had a Matrix Block Type with a handle of `MyMatrixBlock` and it had a Plain Text field with a handle of `text`, this is how you'd grab it in PHP.

```
$entry = Craft::$app->getEntries()->getEntryById(2);

foreach ($entry->matrix as $matrixBlock) {
    if ($matrixBlock->getType()->name === 'MyMatrixBlock') {
        // Grab a text field from the block.
        $textField = $matrixBlock->text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it read "... with a name of MyMatrixBlock ..."? If you used the handle you'd need to change the code to "... getType()->handle === ...".